# SharePoint 2010 Content Type setting ShowInNewForm to FALSE not working

Tags: content-type

I'm trying to create a Content Type that derives from the default Task type in SharePoint 2010.

I wan't to hide some of the fields from the new content type so they are not shown in the new form. I wan't to show all the fields in the disp form.

I have tried setting the ShowInNewForm=FALSE in the content type, but that does not seem to work..

The idea is to have something like this.

- Task type 1
- Task type 2
- etc.

And for each of these types different fields a shown to the user on the new form.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You certainly can do this in CAML or with C# code. Could you post the code you used to the try to set ShowInNewForm attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the inherits and overwrite attributes of the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using InfoPath to design the form? I have heard that InfoPath forms don't respect the ShowInNewForm flag and you need to set this directly in InfoPath when designing the form.